# how to declare an array with explicit type in vlang?

Tags: arrays, variable-declaration, vlang

I am trying to declare an array like below

```golang
arr := [
  [0, 0],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 4],
]

// type: [][]int
```

but the type I am getting from the inference is `[][]int`, instead I want to declare `[][]float32`. When I tried the below syntax I got `[][]f64`.

```golang
arr := [
  [0.0, 0],
  [1.0, 2],
  [2.0, 4],
]

// type: [][]f64
```

what I want is a simple way like the below, we can declare in `c`

```c
float arr[][2] = {
    {0, 0},
    {1, 2},
    {2, 4}
};

// type: f32
```

I was reading the v docs but couldn't find any information about how to give explicit type in the array.

Comment: Did you try casting the float values?  -> f32(0.0)  f32(1.0)  f32(2.0) ?  I don't see a mention of an "f32 literal format", just that a numeric literal like 2.0 is considered f64.

Comment: Yes, that is working, but I need to cast for every element is there any better way?

Answer (score 3):

V will "automagically" infer types by the type of the first element:

```
arr := [
    [f32(0), 0],
    [f32(1), 2],
    [f32(2), 4],
]
println('${typeof(arr)}')
println(arr)
// -> [][]f32
// -> [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 4.0]]
```

Another, shorter, way is to initialize it first, but then you will not have initial values:

```
a := [][]f32{len: 3, init: []f32{len: 2}}
println('${typeof(a)}')
println(a)
// -> [][]f32
// -> [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey thanks for trying out V!

From the [documentation](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#multidimensional-arrays), you can initialise an array either the way you are doing: explicitly listing all elements, or pre-allocate with initial values using a dedicated syntax. Let's see how we can get the code to work both ways.

### Explicit Declaration

```
arr := [
    [f32(0), 0],
    [f32(1), 2],
    [f32(2), 4],
]
println(arr)
println(typeof(arr).name)
```

#### Output:

```
> v run example.v
[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 4.0]]
[][]f32
```

When you declare an array with all the elements listed, you only need to specify the type of the first element. The types for the rest can be inferred, assuming they are primitive. If you omit the `f32()` typecast for the rest of the arrays, the internal type inference assumes the arrays are `[]int` or `[]f64` which leads to compilation errors.

It does make sense to allow hinting the compiler that we will be working with `f32`s exclusively so that we won't have to cast the first element of every sub-array. Consider making a [feature request on Github](https://github.com/vlang/v/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Feature%20Request&projects=&template=feature-request.yml).

### Initialisation Syntax

```
arr := [][]f32{len: 3, init: []f32{len: 2, init: (index + 1)}}
println(arr)
println(typeof(arr).name)
```

#### Output:

```
> v run example.v
[[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]]
[][]f32
```

This example shows the struct-like method of declaring and initialising an array. Here, we specify up-front that we want a 2D `[][]f32` array. Inside, we specify that the nested arrays are 1D `[]f32` arrays. We make use of the `index` variable for the `init` expression. I suggest keeping the array mutable using `mut arr := ...` if you want to modify the elements later.

Instead of using `len` you might also use `cap` to specify a capacity. Then you might use a `for` loop to push arrays to the outer array using the `<<` operator. See [this section](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#array-initialization) for more examples.